# Controller to maintain a stable amplitude

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I am recording a channel before and after injecting current into that channel. I control the current injection using a switch, when the switch is on current goes to the channel, when the switch is off current is off.
My aim is to have a similar amplitude in the channel before and after the current injection.

So currently, I am storing data from the channel before the switch (X), and store data after the switch (Y). I want the data before and after the switch to equal each other (X=Y).
The more the switch is on , the higher the amplitude (Y) is in comparison to A, and the opposite is true.

The duration of the switch being ON is what I can control in order to have the amplitude before and after equal.

Would using a PID control be a right way to start?

Comment: Are you controlling a system using a PWM signal? your switching story sounds a lot like that.  My question is then, what physical aspect should the PID controller control? Alternatively, can an energy storing device like a capacitor not do the same?

Comment: Amplitude of what? voltage? current? electric field? A neurochemical state? What is being switched? What is being measured? What do you know about the dynamics of the system? If you want to keep it as an abstract control question, that is fine too, but then please draw a system diagram to make it clear on that level. Thanks